# Submitted data saving to MySQL as 1 for VarChar, 0 for Int

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create something similar to Facebook for my semester project, and having some problems.

When I post values via form and try to save it in my database, the data stored in database is like 1 for VarChar data type and 0 for Int data type.

I am unable to find the error. My HTML and PHP code is below:

```
<?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_password="vertrigo";
$db_name="php_db";

mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password) or die("Couldn't connnect  to the database");
mysql_select_db("php_db") or die("Couldn't connnect to the database");

?>

<form name="reg" action="signup.php"  method="post">

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table width="440" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2"   cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td><div align="left">First Name:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div align="left">Last Name:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><div align="left">Address:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div align="left">Country:  </div></td>
    <td><select name="country" >
    <option value="Select Country:"> Select Country: </option>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
    <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
    <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
    <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
    <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
    <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
    <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
    <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
    <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
    <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
    <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
    <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
    <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
    <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
    <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
    <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
    <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
    <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
    <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean       Territory</option>
    <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
    <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>

    </select>
    <div align="left"></tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div align="left">Contact No.:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="contact" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div align="left">  Your Email:  </div> </td>
    <td>    <div align="left"> <input type="text" name="email"  size="25" class="inputbox" /> </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div align="left">  Re-enter Email:  </div>  </td>
    <td><div align="left"> <input type="text" name="remail"  size="25" class="inputbox" /> </div></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>    
    <td><div align="left"> New Password:  </div> </td>
    <td><div align="left"> <input type="password" name="password" size="25"   class="inputbox" /> </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div align="left">Gender:  </div></td>
    <td><div align="left">
    <select name="gender" >
    <option value="Select Gender:"> Select Gender: </option>
    <option value="Female"> Female </option>
    <option value="Male"> Male </option>
    </select>
    </div></td>       
    <td>&nbsp;</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><div align="right"></div></td>
    <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>

    <?php
    include 'connection.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){


    $first_name = isset( $_POST['fname']);
    $last_name = isset($_POST['lname']);
    $address = isset($_POST['address']);
    $country = isset($_POST['country']);
    $contact = isset($_POST['contact']);  
    $email = isset($_POST['email']); 
    $remail = isset($_POST['remail']); 
    $pw = isset($_POST['password']); 
    $gender = isset($_POST['gender']); 



$query=  mysql_query(" INSERT INTO fb_sign (fname, lname,  address,country,     contact, email,
    remail, password, gender) VALUES('$first_name', '$last_name',   '$address'  , '$country', 'contact', '$email', '$remail', '$pw', '$gender')");

    if(! $query )
        {
            die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    else
        { 
            echo "Registered successfully!\n";
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hopefully if anyone else has this same issue, they can Google "i am trying to create facebook for my semester project, i am facing some difficulties kindly help me out" to find the answer.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of re-wording to "something similar to Facebook", assuming that your colleague isn't working on a time machine for you to go back and sell the result to Mark Zuckerberg. More seriously, try to concentrate your questions here on one specific problem, not the wider project that problem happens to be a part of.

Comment: @IMSoP i'm sorry for my mistake, thanks for re wording :)

Answer (score 3):

You're setting all your variables to the result of `isset($_POST['XXX'])`, which is either `true` or `false`, not to the value of the input field itself. So

```
$first_name = isset($_POST['fname']);
```

should be:

```
$first_name = isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : '';
```

and similarly for all the other variables.

Comment: @bamar it worked, thumbs up for ur help :)